# Reversing pow function - finding the power

Tags: python, math, pow

If I have:

```
B = pow(g, b, p)
```

and know the values of B, g and p, is there an easy way to find b?

Comment: First consider just the 2-argument form of `pow`:  `B = pow(g, b)`, which is the same as `B = g ** b`.  Then `b = log(B)/log(g)`, or using the 2-argument form of `log`, `b = log(B, g)`, where `log` comes from the `math` package.  Inverting the 3-argument version of `pow` is not well defined since the answer isn't unique.